# Animation optimization for many identical vector shapes in AS3/AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, events, optimization, bitmap, rendering

I have many small, identical vector circles that move around the screen, but only appear for a defined period in defined areas. Currently, these circles are children of whatever parent object produces them, and each is given its own interframe handler for animation (move a few pixels, maybe change alpha). With hundreds on screen, this gets somewhat slow.

Would it be advisable to cache the circles as bitmaps? Would it be better to add them all to one array and have one interframe event handler run through the whole shebang, even if up to 90% aren't being animated in a specific frame?

Would it be faster to cache one circle as a bitmap and set all others to use the first shape's bitmapdata? Would it be even better to use a "CopyPixel" approach to erase and redraw ("blit") every circle at its new position every frame? I hear conflicting reports of the usefulness of CopyPixel on large mobile device canvases...

Answer (score 0):

If the animation can be looped make a movie from the movie else try everything you can. Usually a CopyPixel approach is faster but I wouldn't expect much. I don't think it pays the bill either hence reduce the numbers of circles.